# Worldpay Direct XML

Tags: xml, worldpay

When I submit XML to https://secure-test.WorldPay.com/jsp/merchant/xml/paymentService.jsp:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?> <!DOCTYPE paymentService PUBLIC "-//WorldPay/DTD WorldPay PaymentService v1//EN" "http://dtd.worldpay.com/paymentService_v1.dtd"><paymentService version="1.4" merchantCode="WPACC48193806"> <submit> <order orderCode="AU-1746976-13714703"> <description>Personalised Working Holiday Guide to Australia/Working Holiday, Account No. AU-13714703</description> <amount value="3000" currencyCode="GBP" exponent="2"/> <paymentDetails> <VISA-SSL> <cardNumber>4917610000000000</cardNumber> <expiryDate> <date month="5" year="2022"/> </expiryDate> <cardHolderName>Nguyen Quang</cardHolderName> <cvc>234</cvc> <cardAddress> <address> <street>abc,abc,abnc</street> <postalCode>1000</postalCode> <city>323.84</city> <countryCode>GB</countryCode> <telephoneNumber>+44</telephoneNumber> </address> </cardAddress> </VISA-SSL> <session shopperIPAddress="164.194.163.93" id="186002" /> </paymentDetails> <shopper> <shopperEmailAddress>quang021@ekabiz.vn</shopperEmailAddress> <browser> <acceptHeader>text/html</acceptHeader> <userAgentHeader>Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3; MS-RTC LM 8; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)</userAgentHeader> </browser> </shopper> </order> </submit> </paymentService>
```

When I run this, this is what is output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE paymentService PUBLIC "-//WorldPay//DTD WorldPay PaymentService v1//EN"
                                "http://dtd.worldpay.com/paymentService_v1.dtd">
<paymentService version="1.4" merchantCode="WPACC48193806"><reply><orderStatus orderCode="AU-1746976-13714703"><error code="7"><![CDATA[Payment Method VISA_CREDIT-SSL is unknown; The Payment Method is not available.]]></error></orderStatus></reply></paymentService>
```

The documentation says to add your IP address for requests to your Worldpay account, which I think I have done correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Old question that I upvoted because I had the same problem, for us the problem was there is a maximum transaction value against a WorldPay account. If your transaction value exceeds this, it also returns the error above. The default is GBP 2,500, but can be increased by contacting WorldPay.

Comment: not looking forward to integrating with WorldPay. Some of the worst docs I've ever seen.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your Worldpay admin section you can specify what cards you accept.  It seems like you have got your payment gateway configured to not accept VISA Credit cards.  I suggest checking this and then trying.